# How to install prob package in R

Tags: r

I am using 4.3.1 version of R and I am using R studio as IDE. It does not have prob package. I clicked on install packages and it does not show the prob package. from where and how to install it? please help

i tried library(prob) and clicked on install in Rstudio but does not show prob package. The prob package provides some common sample spaces like tossing coins, rolling dice, deck of cards,etc. i need it for these problems

Comment: Discussion here: https://community.rstudio.com/t/installation-prob-package/157668

Comment: What is the alternative to it? For example if I have problems like roll dice and toss coin , how to do them without prob

Answer (score 2):

I was able to successfully install the prob package (and the required dependencies) using [remotes](https://github.com/r-lib/remotes) by installing the packages in this order:

```r
install.packages("remotes")
library(remotes)
remotes::install_github("cran/fOptions")
remotes::install_github("cran/fAsianOptions")
remotes::install_github("cran/prob")
```

For this approach, you need to have a working compiler (e.g. gcc) and fortran (gfortran) installed. You can install these 'installation tools' via [macos-rtools](https://github.com/coatless-mac/r-macos-rtools) (for macOS) or [rtools](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html) (windows)

Comment: thank you but this approach looks pretty complex and need lot of installations.

Comment: Yes. Stackoverflow is a site for programmers - if you are a beginner there are much better resources and places to go for help. If you are a student, your course coordinator would be the best person to contact. Good luck!

Comment: Yes I agree. I am not a programmer but a student but find this site helpful.thank you!

Comment: You're welcome; if you only want to toss a coin and roll a dice you can write the functions yourself e.g. https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/411402_d893dee68d164d1a9e2ce49b62ea99aa.html